# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, arcgis, arcpy

I'm programming in python with OpenCv libraries.

I'm trying to delete shades using opencv, so after that I want to calculate NDVI (Arcpy libraries). So if I calculate NDVI from the original image, it is work fine, but if i want to calculate NDVI from the result after eliminate shades, i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Python27/sombras_ndvi.py", line 36, in <module>

    NIR = arcpy.sa.Raster(sumada3+ '\Band_1')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

The complete code is this:

```
#I create a workspace to calculate NDVI..

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

env.workspace = r'C:\python27\archivos'

#the first step is apply some filters to finally delete shades.

img = cv2.imread('C:\python27\Archivos\image02.jpg',0)

orig = cv2.imread('C:\python27\Archivos\image02.jpg')


thresh = 45
maxValue = 255

blur = cv2.blur(img, (15,15))

medianblur = cv2.medianBlur(blur,11)

th, dst = cv2.threshold(blur, thresh, maxValue, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)


dst2_3channel= cv2.cvtColor(dst,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) 

sumada3 = cv2.add(dst2_3channel,orig)

#NOW I TRY TO CALCULATE NDVI


NIR = arcpy.sa.Raster(sumada3+ '\Band_1')

red = arcpy.sa.Raster(sumada3+ '\Band_2')

#NDVI = (NIR-red)/(NIR+red)

num = arcpy.sa.Float(NIR-red)

denom = arcpy.sa.Float(NIR+red)

NDVI = arcpy.sa.Divide(num, denom)

ndvi_out = ('NDVI_sombras.jpg')

NDVI.save(ndvi_out)
```

Comment: `sumada3` is a numpy array of pixel values, whereas `'\Band_1'` is a string. As the error message says, the `+` operation is undefined for this combination of input types. It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do here. What is `'\Band_1'` supposed to represent? What sort of object should the result of `sumada3 + '\Band_1'` be?

Answer (score 0):

[`arcpy.sa.Raster`](http://resources.arcgis.com/de/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000051000000) creates a raster object. However, it requires an existing *raster dataset* as an input. It cannot accept a numpy array as input; the appropriate tool for that is [`arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster`](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//03q30000007q000000).

Comment: On top of that, appending `\Band_1` is not going to select a layer of a numpy array. You may need to dig further into the documentation of numpy arrays to figure that out.